grid lines not showing behind transparent bar in google bar chart
In the tornado chart I have 4 data columns , whereas the first one is white in order to create the look of the tornado chart.

Now the problem is that the gridlines are not showing because of the white bar. I have tried several ways to make the white bar transparent but it does not seem to work. I tried e.g.:
series: {
        0: {
          color: '#ffffff',
          fillOpacity: 0 // Set opacity to 0.2 (20% opacity)
        },
        1: {
          color: '#6898EE',
          fillOpacity: 1 
        },
        2: {
          color: '#2343CF',
          fillOpacity: 1 
        }
      },

It doesn't work. Is there a trick in google charts to make a bar transparent?

try --> color: 'transparent'

wau, that worked, thank you so much. Can you please make this an answer so that I can tick it off. Thanks

google charts allows a transparent color name...
color: 'transparent'

